# Cluster in opendaylight

Tags: cluster-computing, sdn, opendaylight

I am trying to set up cluster according to this manual

https://docs.opendaylight.org/en/stable-magnesium/getting-started-guide/clustering.html

But i also woukd  like to know how does it work.
There is written that i choose which node/controller is leader and which will follow after 
 leader is down using member role - 1 - 2 in akka.config. 
But in some work i have read it is using RAFT algorithm to choose/elect leader. Am i mixing it up somehow? 
Can someone explain it to me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The nodes you specify [when setting up an OpenDaylight cluster](https://docs.opendaylight.org/en/stable-magnesium/getting-started-guide/clustering.html#setting-up-a-multiple-node-cluster) are all equal, there is no pre-selection of a leader. When the cluster starts up, the controller nodes will participate in a RAFT election to choose the leader.